# Patch data with Vue Js and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I try to update an existing field, but I get that row id is undefined.
I try to do this in several ways but no result till now.
If I hard code the id (ex example.dev/customers/5), I get error 500.

Any help,please?

```
    <b-table show-empty :items="items.data" :fields="fields">
        <template v-slot:cell(actions)="row">
            <b-button v-b-modal.modal-prevent-closing-update> Edit </b-button>
        </template>
    </b-table>

    <b-modal
        id="modal-prevent-closing-update"
        ref="modal"
        @ok="updateName(items.data.id)"
    >
        <form ref="form" @submit.stop.prevent>
        <b-form-group label=" Name" label-for="name-input">
            <b-form-input id="name-input" v-model="name"></b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>
        </form>
    </b-modal>


export default {
    data() {
      return {
        items: [],
        name: ''
       }
    }
    updateName() {
        axios
        .post("/customers/" + this.items.id, {
            name: this.name,
            _method: "patch"
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    },
}
```

**Laravel-route and controller**

```
Route::patch('/customers/{customer}', 'CustomersController@update');

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string',
    ]);
    $customer->update($data);
    return response($customer,200);
}
```

Comment: What are the Laravel logs saying about the 500 error?

Comment: Foreign key violation, I will take a closer look on my api. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have never defined your `$customer` variable in your controller's action.

You can make use of Laravel's Route Model Binding by updating your controller method's signature from:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
```

To:

```php
public function update(Request $request, Customer $customer)
```

Replace `Customer` by your model class.

You can read more about route model binding here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already passing the ID in the method, why don't you use that one:

```
updateName(id) {
    axios.post("/customers/" + id, {
        name: this.name,
        _method: "patch"
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
},
```

Because as far as I can see your `items` is an array, on which you add an object `items.data` so it might be that you need to access it using a key `this.items[0].data.id` or something like that.

Or just use `console.log` and check what does `this.items` returns before the axios request.

Comment: This solve the problem with row id. Also add   " id = this.items.data[0].id " to your answer, to accept it. Thank you!